# TinyMCE default font size

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce

How can I set the default font size of tinyMCE , I've a tinyMCE editor and I tried all the things to change the  text-size to 14px and it always shows 10px. I'm using rails 3.1 and tinymce 
**major Version: '3', and minor Version: '4.4'**.

I changed tinymce/themes/advanced/skins/default/content.css font-size to 14px
I even add

```
tinyMCE.init({
    theme_advanced_font_sizes: "10px,12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px",
    font_size_style_values: "12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px",
});
```

and

```
body, td, pre { color: #000; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 14px; margin: 8px; }
```

Comment: Did you empty your browser's cache? Sometimes you have to do that to ensure TinyMCE is not using an older file.

Comment: Thanks bro!! U save my day....kill me..

Comment: @tuva: I know this is an old post. But just today I came accross this and I also edited the content.css and it did not work no matter if I cleared my cache or not. Then I found it on the tinyMCE website: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:content_css that you actually have to make a copy of the content.css file otherwise (so they say) it will have no effect. Which makes Jona's answer the correct one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to empty you browser's cache. Sometimes you have to do that to ensure TinyMCE is not using an older file.

[As @Jona and @Nikola said, please make sure you are referencing a new CSS flle].

Answer (score 7):

You can load a [custom stylsheet](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:content_css) for the textarea:

```
tinyMCE.init({
  content_css : "custom_content.css"
});
```

In there you can style your fonts like on a normal page.