# Tinymce default styles in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I was following the tutorial on [How to build a blog with Rails 5 and Bootstrap 4 - Part 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8C9HjGb0IA), initialized Tinymce Editor but I can't change the default font size of text in this editor. I have this code in application.js:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  tinymce.remove();
  tinymce.init({
      selector: 'textarea#post_body',
  height: 500,
  plugins: [
      "advlist autolink autosave link image lists charmap",
      "wordcount media code",
      "table contextmenu textcolor paste"
    ],
  toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | styleselect formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect",
  toolbar2: "cut copy paste | bullist numlist | outdent indent blockquote | link image media | forecolor | table | subscript superscript | charmap | code",
  menubar: false,
  content_css : "/assets/application.css"
});
```

})

In application.css:

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";
```

And there are other two files with styles (custom.scss and posts.scss). I tried putting in custom.scss:

```
body.mce-content-body {
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: gray;}

body.mce-content-body p {
    font-size: 16px;}

[data-mce-style] {
    font-size: 16px;}
```

I also tried the following:

-clearing browser cache several times

-copying custom.scss and linking to the new file in content_css as per [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041840/tinymce-default-font-size)

-using `content_style: ".mce-content-body p { font-size: 16px;}"`

The file is being added to the head of the iframe and its background color is changing, but the styles for paragraphs are always being overwritten by their default inline styles :`<p style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px 0px 1.1em; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-size: 19.35px; line-height: 32.895px; font-family: Lato, sans-serif; color: #444444;" data-mce-style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px 0px 1.1em; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-size: 19.35px; line-height: 32.895px; font-family: Lato, sans-serif; color: #444444;">...</p>`

Another problem is that even if I change the background-color while editing post, the default styles are back when I submit the form and show all blog posts :(

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Do you have git repo of your project?

Comment: [here it is](https://github.com/IoPhoenix/svetlana_stupina/)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it. The problem was in 16px instead of 16pt :-) Tinymce4 uses default pt style. So just change your `custom.scss` to 16pt:

```
/* TinyMCE specific rules */
body.mce-content-body {
font-family: $raleway;
background-color: gray;
font-size: 16pt;
}

body.mce-content-body p {
   font-size: 16pt;
}
```

Although you can change default [style format](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-formatting/#fontsize_formats) but I haven't tried.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! It turned out, my previous solutions work fine when I create the new post, but they didn't when I tried editing the old posts...

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer accepted if helped in solving the problem. Please check this link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work